# Comic Sans MS on Mobile Devices

Tags: css, fonts

I know Comic Sans MS is a hated font. But I'm trying to create a "legacy" site for a person who loved to use Comic Sans. His usage of that font was a common joke of those close to him.

So I have a button on my site that lets people toggle so that all the text is Comic Sans.

I have everything in place, and it worked on my desktop. But it's not working on mobile.

(I've disabled it at the moment.)

I know I can use Comic Neue ([here](http://comicneue.com/)). But before I fall back on that option, I was wondering if there is a way to get true Comic Sans MS to work. Should I host the .ttf file on my site and link to it? (I'm not even sure that that is legal. Unsure of the copyright rules surrounding that font.)

I couldn't find an online font repository to import it from either.

Do any of you know an easy solution?

Comment: You can host it as a web font, not TTF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft owns the license for Comic Sans.  You're allowed to reference it, but to host the TTF, you will need the server license.  You can purchase it through Monotype, Microsoft's official re-seller.

[Microsoft Font Info](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/Fonts/family.aspx?FID=3)

[Monotype Microsoft Font Library](http://catalog.monotype.com/family/microsoft-corporation/comic-sans)

Comment: As @uncoder mentions, you can also use a webfont. Fonts.com seems to offer their library as webfonts for $10/month.